# Stacked and Grouped Chart with ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

I'm trying to convert from Fusion Charts to the builtin ExtJS 4 charts and I can't find a way to create a [Stacked and Grouped Chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped). Has anyone been successful getting this to work with ExtJS 4?

Comment: Been using highcharts as the main charting system in my project :) Did you mean you want to create such charts in pure ExtJS4?

Comment: @LionelChan: Yeah, I wanted to replicate the linked chart in pure ExtJS. From my brief experience with the new charting api it seems significantly less powerful than what they were offering in ExtJS 3 especially when it comes to configuring the chart with a store's metadata.

Comment: Yes. It's less powerful without store, but in my project in fact I created my own component which reads HighCharts configuration and create charts on the fly :)

Comment: @LionelChan: It looks like I'll be digging into HighCharts tomorrow.

Comment: Did either of you guys figure this out? I need this for a project I'm working on and would love a pointer or two.

Comment: @Pie21 Negative. I'm still trying to figure something out.

Comment: @Pie21 I just found this https://github.com/JoeKuan/Highcharts_ExtJs_4 It might be the only suitable alternative.

Comment: @rwilliams Nice find. Wrapping a Highchart would be good enough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is possible with the bundled charting in ExtJS. I'd recommend High Charts or Fusion Charts.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, You should add the second bar series and for each use render handler like this:

```
renderer: function(sprite, config, rendererData, index){ var w = config.width;
config.width = 30;
config.x = config.x + (w-30)/2 - 20; <--- -20 for first bar and + 20 for second

}
```

[Source](http://%20https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179142-How-to-create-a-stacked-and-grouped-column-chart&p=1051388&viewfull=1#post1051388):